# APACHEDS 2.0 - LDIF command line import on windows maschine

Tags: command-line, import, apacheds, ldif

I'm looking for a way to import a ldif file into a apacheDS 2.0 LDAP server. I've seen there was a way with 1.5 and the apacheds-tools.jar but this seems to be removed.

Is there another easy way to get the task done?

Comment: According to this link there seems to be a command line option for Apache Directory Studio, but how do I run these commands? https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.1.1-adding-entries.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Directory Studio for this.

Just start it, connect to your directory, right-click on "Root DSE" or any other element of the directory and choose "Import" -> "LDFI import".

It is also described here: https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.1.1-adding-entries.html

To get the required tools for windows, your can install OpenLDAP (you can get it here: http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx), the client tools contain a **ldapmodify.exe** (in `\OpenLDAP\ClientTools\`).

To use the command line tools on linux you need to install the package **ldap-utils** (apt-get install ldap-utils).

Then you can do the following:

```
ldapmodify -h hostname -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w adminpassword -a -f your-file.ldif
```

Replace:

**hostname** with hostname 

**10389** with the port on which your directory server is running

**"uid=admin,ou=system"** with the DN of the (probably admin) user you want to use for connecting

**10389** with the password of the user

**your-file.ldif** with the path of your ldif file

For more information, you can have a look at this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DIRxSRVx10/2.2.2.+Command+line+tools